# Android IN App purchase - Item already owned issue

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have multiple items in my app. I have two devices. If I buy item on first of these devices and then try to buy on another one the same item, i can't.(Google play intent shows message - Item already owned! And then it crashes....:-( ) Items in google play are marked as "managed per user account". And I do not have any problem with buying items.

Another problem is, if I try RESTORE TRANSACTION ACTION - I got result_developer_error ( which is partly weird....):D

These issues tested on Android 2.2,4.1

My question is:

1. Is there any possibility to allow to buy this item multiple times without need that the item is marked as "unmanaged"? (I mean on different devices by the phrase multiple times)
2. If there is possibility? Can it be done without server side where the info will be stored?

I know that the simpliest solution is to change product_type - But then I will loose the chance for restore transaction action....

I followed google api on implementing the in-apps
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

note: implemented v2 in - apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally solved this issue by implementing new v3 in app billing. It's quite simple to implement version3 and it supports checking for transactions in very very better way. If I could i would send plus one to google for version3. If you are lookng for solution for this issue use this site ["Google in app billing version 3"](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html)

Answer (score 3):

Managed items are tied to your account. So if you buy on a different device with the same Google account, you will get the 'already owned' error. If you use unmanaged items, you can buy the item as many times as you want. In this case you might need to track item state on your own server, if required. If you are using a test account to test this, restore transactions doesn't really work. Should work with a published app though.

In-app billing v3 handles this differently and should be slightly easier to manage. If this is for a new implementation, consider switching (or at least evaluating) v3. Not clear how stable (or not) it is though, since it is pretty new.

Comment: The app is already published and this was tested with real accounts also. The problem persist. (Mean problem with restore transactions..) 
So you suggest to change type of in app products? 

I know this is different answer - but is there any way to change type without need of changing the inapp id???(Which means changing implementation slightly and recreating all in apps on google dev. console.... )M

Comment: No, I don't suggest to change the type. And no, you cannot change the type without adding a new item. Developer error usually refers to not having signed with the release certificate or testing an app with different version from what is published.